# Nested file upload in Grocery CRUD

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I need nested file uploader for codeignitor grocery CRUD.

If i Select one file, again file chooser should appear.

Help me to do this

[image]

Comment: hope this article will help http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/09/10/Adding-a-file-display-list-to-a-multifile-upload-HTML-control

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Grocery CRUD, but I found this thread on Grocery CRUD's forums:
[Link](http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/1912-updated-30072013-multiple-uploading/)

Hopefully its useful to you